# angular 5 chart.js Failed to create chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular5

I recently added chart.js to my angular 5 projects and I'm trying to create a line type chart but I have an error: `Failed to create a chart: can't acquire context from the given item` in browser console how can I solve this issue?

```
public chart = [];
ngOnInit() {
this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        datasets: [
          {
            title: "Some Data",
            values: [25, 40, 30, 35, 100],
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
        }
      }
    });
}
```

component html:

```
<div *ngIf="chart">
  <canvas #canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html) said:

> To create a chart, we need to instantiate the Chart class. To do this,
>   we need to pass in the node, jQuery instance, or 2d context of the
>   canvas of where we want to draw the chart

So your code should look like this:

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        datasets: [
          {
            title: "Some Data",
            values: [25, 40, 30, 35, 100],
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
          },
        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: why `Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement`

Comment: I update my answer. You are using typescript and it uses strict type! ;)

Comment: You're welcome bro. Don't forget to mark it as resolved! :D

Comment: i know i had time limitation :D

Answer (score 4):

in component.html

The problem is the *ngIf. The canvas doens't exist as long as *ngIf == false and can thus not be found by chart.js. Change the  tag into  and it should work

```
<div [hidden]="!chart">
  <canvas id="canvas">{{ chart }}</canvas>
</div>
```